# Kotlin convert List with nullables to HashMap without nullables

Tags: collections, kotlin, nullable

I have incoming param `List<Somedata>`.
`Somedata` class contains `id` field.
**My goal** is to make `HashMap<Somedata.id, Somedata>` from this `list`.

Is next approach correct or there is a better/safer way to do that?

```
list
    .filter { it.id != null }
    .associateTo(HashMap(), {it.id!! to it})
```

Actually, I cannot understand, why should I use `!!` keyword in `associateTo` method, when above I filtered it with non-null values only.

Or maybe there is a good way to perform this with `?.` or `?.let` keywords?

Comment: Just a nitpick: `?.let` isn't a keyword, it's a call to the extension function `let` using the `?.` safe call operator.

Comment: Thanks, I just started with Kotlin, so may confuse with such a things now )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
list.mapNotNull { e -> e.id?.let { it to e } }.toMap()
```

Breakdown:

The call to `.let` with the `?.` safe call operator will make the result `null` if the element is null.

So the lambda passed to `mapNotNull` is of type `(Somedata) -> Pair<IdType, Somedata>`.

`mapNotNull` discards the null pairs, and `toMap` turns the resulting `List<Pair<IdType, Somedata>>` into a `Map<IdType, Somedata>`.

If you want to avoid the creation of an intermediate list to hold the pairs, you can turn the list into a lazy `Sequence` from the start:

```
list.asSequence().mapNotNull { e -> e.id?.let { it to e } }.toMap()
```

Alternatively, since you asked:

> why should I use !! keyword in associateTo method, when above I filtered it with non-null values only.

this is because the list is still of type `List<Somedata>` - this says nothing about the nullability of the *field* itself. The compiler does not know that the `id` fields are *still* not null, by the time your `associateTo` call is executed.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot, but resulting map is `Map<Int?, Somedata>`, and I need `HashMap<Int, Somedata>`, ideas to do that?

Comment: @GoltsevEugene oops. I edited my answer, it should work (I can't test it right now, so it may require slight modification.)

Comment: Seems to work now, will check it and need some time now to understand all of this ;) Thanks a lot!!